# CompareAttribute Always Throws Does Not Match ValidationResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was checking the `[CompareAttribute]` in ASP.NET MVC Project and I realized that this declaration is not working properly in MVC 4 Version 5.2.3.0. The runtime version of DataAnnotations library is v4.0.30319.

The problem here is that when I post the *EditView* to the *EditAction* with these values, `EmailAdress = test@test.com`, `ConfirmEmail = test@test.com` the `[CompareAttribute]` throws this `ValidationError` "*EmailAdress and ConfirmEmail is not match*". But you see that these two respective values are the same each other. Could it be a bug or I misunderstand something ?

Let's see the code:

My Partial Employee Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using work18.Models;

namespace work18.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMetaData))]
    public partial class Employee
    {
        [CompareAttribute("EmailAdress")]
        public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }

    }

    public class EmployeeMetaData
    {           
    }
}
```

The Edit Function within the Controller which responds to HttpPost requests:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,FullName,Gender,Age,
        HireDate,EmailAdress,Salary, PersonalWebSite")] Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(employee);
    }
```

So do you have any knowledge or advice about this issue ?

**EDIT PROBLEM SOLVED**

This is because a very very stupid mistake. If you search the code carefully in the Edit action method you will see that there is no `ConfirmEmail` in the include property that's way the error raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the following line:

```
[Bind(Include = "ID,FullName,Gender,Age,
    HireDate,EmailAdress,Salary, PersonalWebSite")
```

in the Edit action method you will see there is no any property such like `ConfirmEmail` so it posted as null to this method. That's way the `[Compare]` attribute get this value as null. If you look at the source code of Compare attribute you will gain the reason.